# If $a \equiv b$ mod n, then $ac \equiv b(c+n)$ mod n

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Show that $a\equiv b$ mod n implies that $ac \equiv b(c+n)$ mod n.

My proof attempt:

If $a \equiv b$ mod n, then $n|(b-a)$ which implies that $(b-a) = nx$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Which implies that $ac \equiv bc$ mod n. Because $n|(bc-ac) \Rightarrow n|(c(b-a)) \Rightarrow n|(n(cx))$.

So now, $ac = b(c+n)$ mod n can be written as $n|(bc+bn-ac)$ which can be reduced to $n|(c(b-a) + bn) \Rightarrow n| (n(cx)+nb) \Rightarrow n| n(cx + b)$.

Anyways, I got marked off for this proof and I'm not positive why. So any input would be valuable.

Comment: Is it because your implication arrows are pointing to the wrong direction?

Comment: Are they? I don't know much about this arrow notation. I just used them to show the next step. Do I need to "build up" to the result, rather than "reduce" to the result?

Comment: Taking this line from your question as an example: $$n\mid(bc-ac) \implies n\mid(c(a-b)) \implies n\mid(n(cx))$$But your goal is to use known information to deduce $n\mid(bc-ac)$, which means your proof should be something like
$$\cdots \implies n\mid (bc-ac)\implies bc\equiv ac \pmod n$$
Or simply, replacing your $\implies$ with $\Leftrightarrow$ would be good enough.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my post. n∣(bc−ac)⟹n∣(c(a−b))⟹n∣(n(cx)) should have been  n|(bc−ac)⇒n|(c(b−a))⇒n|(n(cx)). Is the problem still the same? In any case I'll do what you've suggested.

Comment: I feel like I am being thick. But I thought I proved above that $(b-a)=nx$. So $c(b-a) \Rightarrow n(cx)$.

Comment: +isyoung oh my fault, didn't see that. Then my only complaint is about your implication direction.

Comment: Instead of going through the proof directly you may prove the following two results (1) $a\equiv b\pmod n\implies ac\equiv bc\pmod n$ and (2) $a\equiv b\pmod n\implies a+c\equiv b+c\pmod n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your written implication flow is reversed. Your flow should be from given information (like $a\equiv b\pmod n$) or from true statement (like $n\mid ncx$). So I might write that in this way:

$$\begin{align*}
&&a&\equiv b\pmod n\\
\implies&& n&\mid (b-a)\\
\implies&& n&\mid c(b-a)\\
\implies&& n&\mid c(b-a) + nb \\
\implies&& n&\mid b(c+n) - ac\\
\implies&& ac&\equiv b(c+n) \pmod n
\end{align*}$$

or

Let $a = b + kn$, $k\in\mathbb Z$, then

$$\begin{align*}
ac &= (b+kn)c\\
&= bc + knc\\
&= bc + bn + knc - bn\\
&= b(c+n) + n(kc-b)\\
\implies ac &\equiv b(c+n) \pmod n
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I think this is what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've written anything incorrect but I also don't see how you proved the result. As a side note, statements like $n|(n(cx))$ are meaningless since $n$ divides any multiple of itself. It isn't wrong, but you will only waste space.

Try starting with writing or what you are trying to prove. You want to show $n|(ac-bc-bn)$. Note that $n|(a-b)$ so $n|(ac-bc)$. Thus $ac-bc-bn=mn+bn=(m+b)n$ for some integer $m$. This gives the result.

Comment: Sorry about the obtuse writing. However, I don't understand how you're last line is different from mine.

Comment: Its just that you didn't end with the result, the instructor would have to go back and plug in $nx=b-a$. At this level, you're leaving the instructor to do nearly half of the proof. Again, its not wrong but the instructor is at their discretion to mark down for what they consider unclear.

Comment: You're right. My proof was to ambiguous. I thought it was only necessary to show that &(b(c+n)-ac)$ had a common factor of n. Thanks for the help!